# "Visiting" a URL in PHP

Tags: php, kohana

The way my site is setup, I need to manually visit two URLs to trigger the mail system. One URL compiles a list of emails, another sends them off.

I'd like to automate this using a cronjob, but here's the problem. I am using the Kohana framework and I don't think copy pasting the code within the controllers will work.

The easiest way to accomplish what I am doing is to have the two URLs visited every 5 minutes or so. Is it possible to "visit" (for a lack of better word) sites in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you just use `file_get_contents` or access it by `cURL`, it would be considered "visited" as it will simply create a GET request.

```
file_get_contents($url1);
file_get_contents($url2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to 'visit' a web site you could retrieve it via file_get_contents(), or if you have the curl extension installed you could fire up a curl request at your URLS.

Comment: Looks like shamittomar beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the cron job on the same machine as the server you can call Kohana on the command line using this syntax.

```
/usr/bin/php index.php --uri=controller/action
```

Replace controller/action with the route you wish to call.

Note that any $SERVER variables are not defined when you invoke Kohana in this manner.